# Nodes on the ends of arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'd like to put some text on the start and end of some arrows, like in the following image (but less ugly):

[image: https://i.imgur.com/UpihJep.png]

Is there any way to do this without hardcoding the angles or similar?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Yes, with `node[pos=0]{...}` or `node[pos=1]{...}`.

Comment: That works for percentages, but it doesn't seem to work with `[pos=1cm]` or such.

Comment: You asked about start and end points. And if you want to specify the position of a node as an absolute distance, you can do that with the `decorations.markings` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two way. Most likely are question and answer duplicates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw] at (0,0) (A){A};
\node[circle,draw] at (4,-1) (B){B};
\node[circle,draw] at (4,2) (C){C};
\draw (A) -- (B) node[pos=1]{X};
\draw[decoration={markings, 
    mark=at position 1cm with {
    \node{Y};
    }}, postaction={decorate}] (A) -- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]